# Excel: Use cell reference within formula for formula in another cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2013

I have joined just to ask this question as I'm not sure if it's achievable without VBA.

In column A I have a list of values, let's say A1:A9 contain the values "1000" to "9000" respectively.

In B1 I am counting the values like so (with a text addition to cell) ="SDLT "&COUNT(A4,A7)&" units" with the result "SDLT 2 units".

**My question is how can I have C3 display the combined values of the cells referenced in B1?** (result should be "11000" in this example).

I have played around with INDIRECT and MID to try and find the references but to no avail.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The best approach would be to not use a hardcoded range in B1 (and then try to find and cut it out for reuse), but instead use a reference in B1 and the same one in C3. Even better, don't use a reference, but code the selection criteria (meaning write a formula that finds A4:A7 according to the selection rule in your head instead of writing A4:A7), but that might not be an option.

Comment: Not sure you **really** should want to do this, but check out [`FORMULATEXT()`](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/FORMULATEXT-function-0a786771-54fd-4ae2-96ee-09cda35439c8), which you could combine with some string handling functions to fetch the cells referenced in the formula in `B1` dynamically.

Comment: Aganju your change of logic makes sense. For my application I would need to pull a specific number (2 in the example) of "Random" values from column A. "Random" in this case could be defined in a number of ways, but a simple one that comes to mind would be starting from the largest value and working down and this could be done using the LARGE function for example...

Comment: B1 "SDLT "&(COUNT(LARGE(A1:A9,3),(LARGE(A1:A9,6))))&" units"                                                                                                                        C1 LARGE(A1:A9,3)+(LARGE(A1:A9,6))                                                     This would work for the example and would work for my application but requires editing the formula depending on how many values are needed from column A.

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment, you could for example do this in `C1`:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT(MID(FORMULATEXT(B1),FIND("(",FORMULATEXT(B1))+1,2)),INDIRECT(MID(FORMULATEXT(B1),FIND(")",FORMULATEXT(B1))-2,2)))
```

This makes a few assumptions:

- There are only ever two cells specified in the formula in `B1`
- The list of values in column A never extends beyond row 9
- The formula in `B1` only ever contains a single pair of brackets

These could also be worked around, but hopefully the above at least gives you a starting point for a solution.

Comment: 3N1GM4 that works for my example and is very close to what I need! Point three of your bullets is true, the only variation would be additional values added to the COUNT function. Point 1 and 2 ideally would need to be variable in my application. I have not had time to review your formula and am unfamiliar with FORMULATEXT so can't comment as to whether or not the above is achievable but I will have a look into it

Comment: `FORMULATEXT()` just returns the formula from a cell as a string - I didn't know about it until today either. :) I expect you can work around the other limitations of my suggested solution, as I mentioned in my answer, I just haven't had time to do that myself.

Answer (score 0):

The following works:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT(FILTERXML("<group><element>"&SUBSTITUTE(MID(FORMULATEXT(B1),SEARCH("COUNT(",FORMULATEXT(B1))+6,SEARCH(")",FORMULATEXT(B1),SEARCH("COUNT(",FORMULATEXT(B1)))-(SEARCH("COUNT(",FORMULATEXT(B1))+6)),",","</element><element>")&"</element></group>","/*/*")))
```

We used to write functions this way, except using `GET.FORMULA()` from the old Excel 4 Macro commands. Now, of course, `FORMULATEXT()` makes that completely unnecessary.

One then stripped what was needed from the string, placing the pieces in (auxiliary) Named Ranges and recombined them in the real Named Range using `EVALUATE()` from the old macro commands to handle anything not simply arranged. But with more effort, one can now break the pieces of a parameter (a simple one here, so not much effort to obtain) apart easily using the above trick of creating an XML string and using `FILTERXML()` to parse it.

However, `INDIRECT()` is still needed to turn those text results into real references which `SUM()` can then use properly.

(If interested, the old way of making functions was to basically call it something, like `SPLITCELL` perhaps, and it would be used via the old `ISERROR()` and later `IFERROR()` like so:

```
=IFERROR(OURLOOKUP(A3,D1:F2000,-2),OURLOOKUP)
```

and, of course it errors returning the Named Range itself whose auxiliary Named Ranges tear apart the above formula to get the parameter string and return the appropriate things to the end result Named Range (`OURLOOKUP` in this case).

As I said and have indicated, many easements for the work along the way as Excel kept adding functions, especially `LET()` which let you use In-Cell Named Ranges instead of literal traditional Named Ranges. But it was NEVER easy to do one, and you'd never build it to take all the possible ways parameters could be given to a normal Excel function. Just the ways you expected have them entered by your own users. So the `OURLOOKUP` might only take single cell references, not ranges, Named ranges, Table references, array constants... for the lookup value and might only take a literal range for the lookup range. But ours (which used `INDEX/MATCH` under the hood could take "negative" return columns. (The boss never did understand `INDEX/MATCH`'s logic. Actually, using `OURLOOKUP` held me back on it for many years as I seldom needed to use it as I preferred `VLOOKUP()` in a couple ways and used this myself for any `INDEX/MATCH` work.

Once done, there was NO hard work ever. Just importing the function to spreadsheets one needed it in but we just copied a page from one with it to the new one, then deleted the page, and voila!

Now `LAMBDA()` is supposed to do this kind of thing for us, but... It needs imported into each spreadsheet too... But it takes all parameter kinds which is a huge improvement. And no more need for parsing and converting, or using `IFERROR()`, both very nice and adding much to the ease. We still have `OURLOOKUP` though and a few others. Another nice thing is that `LAMBDA()`'s ease of creation should see us using it a lot more than we ever used these, but we don't much yet. Strange.

But regardless of MS's advertising about "Turing Complete" and so on, you could always write your own functions with only the desktop's resources and no need for VBA, though technically, when we had to call upon the Excel 4 macro commands, that was using a non-desktop resource so... potAto, potAHto in my book, but I suppose, not in others' books.)

Of course, the above can benefit for understanding in a year from `LET()` which was not available in 2016, and can be made into a `LAMBDA()` also, if desired.

However, it does demonstrate a simple way to use the source formula as the basis for a derivative interest and in so doing, making sure the referents in each formula stay chained together.

That is NOT to say the approach is robust as changes to the source formula structure (especially changing from direct cell references to a range, etc., would dynamite its construction assumptions — and many other changes could require follow-on work with it).

Nowadays (2022), probably a `LAMBDA()` that includes `IF()` branching in its formula so that if the cell address is B1 it does the string and if C3 it does the `SUM()` would be good so the input parameters can be entered any acceptable to Excel way and yet the output uses the exact same inputs always, for each cell, so that they are always welded together. Moving either result to another cell would require just a simple change in the `IF()` test itself, not the parameters or the formula, so easy maintenance.